# pass javascript var to php

Tags: javascript, php

i have a crono app in js but i need to pass that var to a modal in php, i have this (its a embed table)

```
<table>
    <thead>

    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th>Tieme</th>
    <th><th>      
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>".$res[0]."</td>
        <td>".$res[1]."</td>
        <td > <form name='crono' class='large-6'>
    <input type='text' name='face' title='Cronomet'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var timeCrono;

        var hor = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var seg = 0;
        var startTime = new Date();
        var start = startTime.getSeconds();

        var startchron = 0;

        StartCrono();


        function StartCrono() {

          if (startchron == 1) {

            if (seg + 1 > 59) {
                min += 1;
            }
            if (min > 59) {
                min = 0;
                hor += 1;
            }
            var time = new Date();
            if (time.getSeconds() >= start) {
                seg = time.getSeconds() - start;
            }
            else {
                seg = 60 + (time.getSeconds() - start);
            }
            timeCrono = (hor < 10) ? '0' + hor : hor;
            timeCrono += ((min < 10) ? ':0' : ':') + min;
            timeCrono += ((seg < 10) ? ':0' : ':') + seg;
            document.crono.face.value = timeCrono;
            setTimeout('StartCrono()', 1000);
             console.log(timeCrono);

        } 
     }   
    function stopChr() {
       startchron = 0;
     $('#data').text(timeCrono);
    }     

    function startChr() {
        startchron = 1;
        StartCrono();
    } 

    </script>
</form> 

</td>   

        <td><input type='button' id='btnstart'onclick='startChr();' class='button' value='START'></td> 
        <td> <a href='#' data-reveal-id='ventana' id='addhrs'><input type='button' id='btnstop'onclick='stopChr();' class='button' value='STOP'></a></td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>";
```

I need the 'timeCrono' value that is in format 00:00:00, when press the stop button (function stopChr) appear a modal with the info all that i have is the text of that value $('#data').text(timeCrono);

> but i need pass that text to a value of a  or something like that also #data is a tag  `<p id='data'></p>`  and the result that i want is like
>    `<p id='data' value='00:00:00'>.`

Comment: view https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX for more information on AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

In order to pass values from JavaScript to server-side code, such as PHP, you need to send the value over the network.

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is one of the ways to do that, and [jQuery makes it easy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to do Ajax queries.